# I want to extract this kind of html table (some values are numbers as images)

Tags: python, pandas, ocr

For this page for instance https://bvb.ro/RapoarteFinanciare/IFC_rf_fs.aspx?s=COTE&d=12/31/2021.

Usually I do something along the lines:

```py
import pandas as pd

bvb_data = pd.read_html('https://bvb.ro/RapoarteFinanciare/IFB_rf_fs.aspx?s=TLV&d=12/31/2021')

bvb_data[0]
```

[image: Example output]

A more complicated solution would be to use Selenium to go to the URL and take a screenshot then use something like Tesseract for OCR.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are expecting. whether you need to do OCR for this corresponding table? If Yes, then go with **easyocr**.

```
import easyocr

reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext('2iPZ5.png')
for detection in result:
        print(detection)
```